# Buying and Selling options for the same stock multiple times in a day?

Tags: united-states, options, option-strategies, regulation

Is it normal that traders **buy** and **sell** options of the same stock on the same day multiple times? For example, in an event of a positive earnings release, the **CALL** options were bought and then sold it after an increase in a few hours. A negative news came out, bought another **PUT** option contract and sold it in the next hours?

1. Are there any regulations from the **SEC** for such type of option trading?
2. Is there any special license from **SEC** or online brokers like **TDAmeritrade** needed to trade options on a day to day basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If so inclined, it is normal for traders to buy and sell options of the same stock on the same day multiple times because after all, traders trade.

In order to trade long  options you need a funded brokerage account and  Level 2 option trading approval.

The only SEC restriction that might come into play is Pattern Day Trader rule which limits you to 3 day trades per rolling 5 business day period if done in a margin account.  To avoid the limitation, you must have $25k in your account.  There is no limit on the number of day trades that can be done in a Cash Account with settled cash.